# While reading limits I thought of this $\binom{x}{y}$ where $y \to x^+$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, binomial-coefficients

While reading *limits* I thought of this $\dbinom{x}{y}$ where $y\to x^+$,

as per my opinion, I think the correct answer to be *undefined*
as $\dbinom{x}{y}$ is defined only when $x \geq y $ but here $x$ is slightly less than $y$,

am I right?

any help would be appreciable

Comment: Hmm? If $x\to y^+$, then $x$ is never less than $y$, right? **EDIT:** Okay, you changed the question after I commented.

Comment: sorry, I've corrected it now.

Comment: if $y \to x^+$ I guess you defined ${x \choose y}$ [with the $\Gamma(s)$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: There's no requirement that $x\geq y$, is there? See [this link](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/binomial_coefficients/) which mentions the most general interpretation. $x$ and $y$ can be complex, so "$\geq$" is meaningless here.

Comment: And using the $\Gamma$ function definition, the limit is $1$, as long as $x$ is not a negative integer.

Comment: and note that the definition with $\Gamma$ (which has the property that $\Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s)$ for every $s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus -\mathbb{N}$) is justified by the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Answer (score 4):

We know that $$ \binom{x}{y} = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(x-y+1)} $$
and that the Gamma function is well defined and continuous for positive numbers, then so is $\binom{x}{y}$.

In this case we also have $\displaystyle \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)} \rightarrow 1$.

And by definition of the Gamma function, since $(x-y+1) \rightarrow 1$, we have $\Gamma(x-y+1) \rightarrow 1$.

Thus we have $$ \binom{x}{y} = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(x-y+1)} \rightarrow 1 $$